# Hands together  for mode ani

Tags: minhag, hands-fingers

The Rebbe Rashab told the previous Lubavicher Rebbe that it was always to Jewish custom to say mode ani with hands together
Did he mean literally?
Any sources that true?
Anyone else except Chabad do it?
Or hands in this position for any other prayer?

[Previous Chabad Rebbe saying his father told him it was always the Jewish custom](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31667&st=&pgnum=246&hilite=)

[התקשרות 623](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=3088&CategoryID=861)
הנחת הידיים ב'מודה אני'
מאת הרב יוסף-שמחה גינזבורג

The above sources in English starting footnote 10 [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/modeh-ani/#_ftn10)

Comment: Modeh Ani was invented about 500 years ago, so it's clearly not literally true.

Comment: @DoubleAA But couldn't it be true that from the moment modeh ani was created that it was always done with hands together?

Comment: FWIW, I never heard of it.

Comment: @Aaron Lots of things that aren't the literal meaning of that sentence could be true....

Comment: to clarify you do it with your hands together next to your head with your head tilted slightly it's not exactly like christian prayer

Comment: @ezra Please explain/clarify

Comment: @hazoriz [here you go.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/PArPb6njJW3XeA9v5) idk if others were also taught this way but this is how i was taught, i dafke remember my rebbi saying it was done this way to not resemble the christian form

Comment: Thank you, Chabad?  you do it sitting?

Comment: @hazoriz yes chabad and i always did it in bed sitting up

Comment: @ezra thank you may G-d Almighty bless you

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/collive.com/rabbi-warns-against-prayer-emoji/amp/

Comment: It's worth noting that outside Habad, there are communities that deem it *forbidden* to engage in such gesticulations whilst reciting Modeh Ani. For example Shu"T Birkhath Uriel (YD Siman 57) places its origin as being in emulation of gentile practice and accordingly comes down strongly against it.